# Can only browse files mounted via gvfs, not open them

Tags: arch-linux, gvfs, pcmanfm

I have a new Arch Linux installation using awesome wm and no desktop environment.  If I put `smb://server/share` as a URI on pcmanfm, the mount succeeds after prompting me for my credentials, and I can browse the files and directories, but not open or copy anything.

Right-clicking and choosing `properties` shows owner and group of `0`, and there aren't any files under `/run/user/...`.  If I mount it as follows (not using gvfs), I can access the files as expected, so I know the server end is working.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server/share /mnt/share -o 'user=user,password=password,workgroup=workgroup'
```

I would really like to get it working under gvfs, because this is a very Windows-heavy workplace and the shares I need to access change frequently.  What could be causing this issue, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a result of not having a `fuse` group, and not being added to that group.  To create the group and get added to it, run:

```
# groupadd fuse
# gpasswd -a [user] fuse
```

Log out and back in to apply the group changes.